NestJS Sequelize: Type Error with Custom Input Type in Create Method
I am currently in the process of upgrading dependencies of a project but I am getting this error a bunch of times for different service functions:
src/data/data.service.ts:59:39 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'DataInput' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Optional<any, string>'.
  Type 'DataInput' is not assignable to type 'Omit<any, string>'.
    Index signature for type 'number' is missing in type 'DataInput'.

59     return this.dataRecordModel.create(data, options);

It's been nearly over a year since I last touched this codebase so trying to determine what the real cause is for this issue. Feels like I'm chasing my tail a little bit as I can't seem to find the culprit:
Service code:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { DataInput } from './dto/data-input.dto';
import { DataRecordDTO } from './dto/data-record.dto';
import { DataRecordModel } from './models/data-record.model';
import { CreateOptions } from 'sequelize';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(DataRecordModel)
    private readonly dataRecordModel: typeof DataRecordModel,
  ) {}

  async create(
    data: DataInput,
    options: CreateOptions = {},
  ): Promise<DataRecordDTO> {
    return this.dataRecordModel.create(data, options);
  }
}

Model:
import { Column, Model, Table, DataType, Index } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import {
  AgeCategory,
  GenderCategory,
  EthnicityCategory,
  DisabilityCategory,
  EducationCategory,
} from '../types/Categories.enum';

@Table({
  timestamps: false,
})
export class DataRecord extends Model {
  @Index
  @Column({ primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true })
  id: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.ENUM(...Object.values(AgeCategory)),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  age: AgeCategory;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.ENUM(...Object.values(GenderCategory)),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  gender: GenderCategory;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.ENUM(...Object.values(DisabilityCategory)),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  disability: DisabilityCategory;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.ENUM(...Object.values(EthnicityCategory)),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  ethnicity: EthnicityCategory;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.ENUM(...Object.values(EducationCategory)),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  highestEducation: EducationCategory;
}

The input type:
import { InputType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@InputType()
export class DataInput {
  @Field(() => AgeCategory, { description: 'Age range provided' })
  age: AgeCategory;

  @Field(() => GenderCategory, { description: 'Gender provided' })
  gender: GenderCategory;

  @Field(() => EthnicityCategory, { description: 'Ethnicity provided' })
  ethnicity: EthnicityCategory;

  @Field(() => DisabilityCategory, { description: 'Disability provided' })
  disability: DisabilityCategory;

  @Field(() => EducationCategory, {
    description: 'Highest educational attainment provided',
  })
  highestEducation: EducationCategory;
}

The DataInput type has always been used this way and has worked fine before. What changes might have caused this issue, and how can I resolve it without resorting to any type casting?
These are my dependencies in my package.json:
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.6.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.6.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^7.11.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.1.6",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^1.1.0",
    "@nestjs/sequelize": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.14",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.23.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1624.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dataloader-sequelize": "^2.3.3",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^7.0.4",
    "graphql-type-json": "^0.3.2",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.8",
    "node-fetch": "^2.7.0",
    "parse-database-url": "^0.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.5",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "postmark": "^2.9.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.3",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.6",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.3.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.18",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.63",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.13",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.38",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.20",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.16",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "supertest": "^6.3.4",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
    "ts-loader": "^8.4.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.15.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.1"
  }

